# Node.js how to cancel a WriteFile operation

Tags: node.js, writefile

Is there a way to cancel a WriteFile operation?

example:

```
     await promises.writeFile(path, data)
```

Comment: First of all, you are mixing the callback and the promise version of `writeFile`. You typically cannot `await` something that takes a callback function as parameter. And no, I'm not aware of any way to cancel a `writeFile` from the buildin `fs` or `fs/promises` module ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to create an [`AbortController`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-abortcontroller) and pass it into your `writeFile` call:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// Some stub values
const tempFilePath = () => `/tmp/foo`
data = 'bar'


const myAbortController = new AbortController()
// With callback
fs.writeFile(tempFilePath(), data, { signal: myAbortController.signal }, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    if(err.name === "AbortError") {
      console.warn("write aborted")
      return
    }
    throw err
  }
})
// Or with promises
fs.promises.writeFile(tempFilePath(), data, { signal: myAbortController.signal })
  .catch((err) =>  {
    if(err.name === "AbortError") {
      console.warn("write aborted")
      return
    }
    throw err
  })
// Or Async/Await
;(async () => {
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile(tempFilePath(), data, { signal: myAbortController.signal })
  } catch (err) {
    if(err.name === "AbortError") {
      console.warn("write aborted")
      return
    }
      throw err
  }
})()

// Somewhere else...
myAbortController.abort()
```

The code is tested and runs in v18, v16, and v14 with the `--experimental-abortcontroller` flag

Comment: cool, I just updated the example since I saw you can use the async/await version that imo is always better, could you provide and example for that too? Thanks!

Comment: @imvenx Added the promise based example

Comment: Sorry I gave the solved before testing it, now  I tested and actually promises.writeFile dont take any signal option parameter (?)

Comment: @imvenx what node version are you on?

Comment: @imvenx it's been available since v14 so if you are using an older version you really need to update.

Comment: @imvenx No thats quite outdated by now. You should update to the latest LTS (v18) and update those types to match.